# How convert string field to hashmap value with mapstruct java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I want map `accountNo` to `argument` value with specific key(I mean key of hashmap), with **mapstrcut**. Any ideas?

**Event** is my target

```java
    private Map<String, Object> argument;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

**AccountRequest** is my source

```java
    private String accountNo;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

I have the mapper as below but I want the opposite one too.

```java
    @Mapping(target = "accountNo", expression = "java(event.getArgument().get(key).toString())")
    AccountRequest eventToAccountRequest(Event event, String key);

    Event accountRequestToEvent(AccountRequest accountRequest); // this is my question
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no out-of-the-box support for mapping from a Bean into a Map. There is however an [open feature](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1218) request for this functionality.

This means that for your example you'll need to do it in a custom mapping.

e.g.

```
    @Mapping(target = "argument", source = "accountNo", qualifiedByName = "accountNoToArgument")
    Event accountRequestToEvent(AccountRequest accountRequest);

    @Named("accountNoToArgument")
    default Map<String, Object> accountNotToArgument(String accountNo) {
        return accountNo == null ? null : Collections.singletonMap("accountNo", accountNo);
    }
```

This would make sure that the rest of the parameters are automatically mapped by MapStruct.

---

Side note about a better mapping for `eventToAccountRequest`. Instead of using an expression you can improve it with a custom mapping method and `@Context`. e.g.

```
    @Mapping(target = "accountNo", source = "argument", qualifiedByName = "argumentToAccountNo")
    AccountRequest eventToAccountRequest(Event event, @Context String key);

    @Named("argumentToAccountNo")
    default String argumentToAccountNo(Map<String, Object> argument, @Context key) {
        return argument == null : null : argument.get(key).toString();
    }
```

Using this you will avoid a potential NPE if `event.getArgument()` is null.

Comment: Thanks, @Filip you mentioned important points, appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a default mapper. Something like:

```
default Event accountRequestToEvent(AccountRequest accountRequest) {
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setArguement(Collections.singletonMap(accountRequest.getAccountNo(), "value"));
    return event;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the map-struct way with annotations, but I think it's not possible for mapping the `Map`.

Comment: Then you need to make a function to convert String to Map, define the source and destination there and then this will then automatically be picked by your already defined function: accountRequestToEvent @Faramarz-Afzali

Comment: Thanks for your help Hosein.